# Passing second attribute per drawed element regardless of element index to the shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have an array buffer with all vertices stored in it and an element array buffer object with all indices pointing at the right vertexes. So far drawing works fine with `glDrawElements()`.

Now I want to give a vertex attribute per drawn element to the shader, regardless what the element index is. I've stored the attributes in another array buffer, but if I use `glVertexAttribPointer()` while having the attribute buffer bound, it selects the elements located at the indexes of the element array buffer, while I would like it to give the attributes in order like they are stored. I don't know if it is possible to bind another element array buffer for that.

Is this possible to achive with the current buffers? If not, is there an alternative, where I don't have to combine the vertexes with the data?

I don't want to combine them in a single interleaved array buffer, because the vertices should used several times, just with different element indexes and data.

Here is a small sketch of the situation (note the second order of the data):

[image]
[Fullscreen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y3Y4.png)

Comment: I spent a while looking at your diagram, but both sides look identical to my eye.

Comment: They are not identical, the order of the data on the right side is another: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6". On the left side it is: "1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6", because of the element buffer. I basically want to send data to the shader, while not influenced by the indices of the element buffer.

Comment: In any case, what you are asking for cannot be done. You only get one element array buffer and it applies to the location that ***all*** vertex attributes are pulled from. You can, however, do something like use a 1D lookup texture or indexed uniform buffer object / shader storage object to store the data for the second array. GL and GLES3 give you `gl_VertexID`, but that is actually the index the shader uses to pull the attributes, so the purpose of this lookup texture would be to re-map the indices. Nothing you could not have done simply on the CPU side in your VBO before drawing though.

Comment: Although, this slipped my mind but AMD has an extension [GL_AMD_interleaved_elements](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/interleaved_elements.txt) that lets you pack indices for individual vertex attributes into the element array.

Comment: The AMD extension looks exactly what I'm looking for. The extension looks pretty new and I don't want to limit the program to only the newest graphics cards. And does the use of that extension play nicely with NVIDIA cards?

Comment: Yeah, the AMD extension is just that... an AMD extension at the moment. About all it requires is a recent AMD driver, it is not a special hardware feature (at least nothing generation defining). As for NV hardware, there is a less flexible extension that can do the same thing under very specific circumstances, known as provoking vertices. Provoking vertex will not help you in this situation, that was why AMD went the extra mile and created another extension that does everything provoking vertex does and more. Hopefully this very new extension will see ARB attention in the next few years.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I would consider this extension more like a hack and think it is very unlikely that something like this is ever going into core. Since one is limited to 8Bit indices if one needs more than 2 attributes, the partical usefullness of this is close to zero. YMMV.

Comment: @derhass While looking at the sample code of the extension, I think it's the right thing for my program. The author of the extension said, "A common scenario in graphics rendering is that several faces share a vertex where, for each face some properties of a vertex (position and texture coordinates, for example) should be common but others must be unique (colors, normals, and so on)". And this is exactly the same scenario in my program. But I will probably just combine the vertex data with my other data. Even if it isn't optimized then, I'm on the safe side and also supported by older cards.

Comment: @derhass: I can think of numerous applications that do not need more than 8-bit indices. I dot a lot of drawing where I could get away with 8-bit indices, but promote the index array to 16-bit because that is what desktop GPUs work with (16/32-bit). The ability to pack extra information into the previously unused extra 8-bits of storage could in fact become very useful. Certainly more useful than provoking vertices have ever been. And since you can store combinations of position/secondary vertex attributes in separate array indices you actually do not need a large discrete set of indices.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm now using a seperate vertex buffer for my objects, and I don't use indices anymore, because it's impossible to do what I wanted to do in the beginning. If you post as answer what you pointed out in the third comment, I'll accept it as solution.